# Ruby on Rails Nested Models breakdown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a beginner in Ruby on Rails and also a beginner in Web Development in general. I was trying to learn the Neste forms on Railscasts ep 196 - 198. I fairly understand the episode until the javascript and helper part. I can still understand the "add_fields" function in javascript but when he started to chain the methods, I just got overwhelmed. Can anyone help and guide this idiot?

application_jquery.js:

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
  $(link).closest(".fields").hide();
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
  end

  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end
end
```

by the way, I'm using Rails 4 if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the exact same problem - I think the problem is that this needs to be refactored for rails4. I've figured out how to get the rest of the code updated to rails 4 (I've posted this on the railcast discussion thread) - but this javascript and helper code doesn't do anything now and we are obviously missing something. Any help from someone would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** I updated the code to what is given in the updated railcast "403 Dynamic Forms" and it works (it's a pro cast).